# Can I use core HTML code in Zend View Helper? If yes then how can i call that helper in view?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have one java script definition in view(.phtml) file. This java script has dynamic parameters like controller name and action name. To avoid duplicate code i want to put this code in helper file.

Now is it possible that i can use pure html and javascript code in helper file? If yes then how can i call that helper in my view file?

Or Is there any other best way to do this?

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom) would not be the solution in this instance. More likely you will want to use a [partial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) (which is a view helper). A view helper is something normally used to `return` a piece of data to the view. A `partial()` or `partialLoop()` is used to display common html in the view (pieces of html that can be reused in multiple views).

Here is an example of a simple view helper, notice it returns a result:

```
<?php

class Zend_View_Helper_FormatDate extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function FormatDate($date) {

        if ($date != NULL) {
            $formatedDate = new DateTime($date);
            $format = $formatedDate->format('M d, Y');

            return $format;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

}
//This is called in the view like any other function
<?php echo $this->FormatDate($date) ?>
```

Now a partial will contain Html (I'm petty sure JS will work as well)

Here is a partial that uses view helpers

```
fieldset><legend>Dates and Qualifications</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Birth Date: </td><td><?php echo $this->escape($this->FormatDate($this->bdate)) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Seniority Date: </td><td><?php echo $this->escape($this->FormatDate($this->sendate)) ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>I'm a Lead:</td><td><?php echo $this->escape(ucfirst($this->ToBool($this->lead))) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lead Date:</td><td><?php echo $this->escape($this->FormatDate($this->ldate)) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>I'm an Inspector:</td><td><?php echo $this->escape(ucfirst($this->toBool($this->inspector))) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Admin Login:</td><td><?php echo $this->escape(ucfirst($this->toBool($this->admin))) ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

call this partial in your view script, the first argument is the path of the partial
the second argument is the data used in the partial

```
<?php echo $this->partial('_dates.phtml', $this->memberData) ?>
```

the data is sent from the controller action as usual `$this->view->memberData = $memberData`
 This is common usage but not the only way to get data to the partial.

in this example the partial is at the default location `/application/views/scripts`

Hope this helps

Comment: I have never used partials. can u please tell me where can I put this partial files and call then in my view files?

Comment: Hey @RockyFord After reading your answer I googled for partial and I found that i can use either partial or render. Can you tell me what would suit in my case? Another question is I have created one folder named partial inside view/scripts to place partial files. Would it be ok?

Comment: yes just make sure you pass the path as partials/partial.phtml. As far as the Render(), with render() you would use the variables available to the view, with a partial you pass in data for the partials use. Render is great for simple or static code and partials work well if you need to pass in objects or arrays or you need the data in the view kept separate from the data in the partial.